# Git redirection windows error

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, cmd

Using windows machine, I am trying to create version.h file that creates a #define that compiles in the git repo hash number. Would like to run a batch file in pre-build command line event in visual studio.
Using the following command

```
call git.exe log -n 1 --format=format:"#define GIT_COMMIT \"%h\"%n" HEAD > version.h
```

Command works when running from command line, but fails when running from batch file.  Error message

```
git.exe log -n 1 --format=format:"#define GIT_COMMIT \"n" HEAD > version.h
fatal: ambiguous argument '>': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Please help?

Comment: Did you try using the cmd.exe escape character? `^"n"`

Comment: In a Batch file you have to double the percent signs: `... GIT_COMMIT \"%%h\"%%n" HEAD ...`

Comment: If you are more familiar with unix shell (like me) you could write a bash script and run it with `..\bash.exe -c SCRIPT`.

Comment: @max630 That reminds me the new "Bash on Windows" thingy.